# What are some recommendations for books, when talking strictly about programming against the Object Model API for SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, oop, sharepoint-api

I've read quite few books regarding programming for SharePoint 2007, but in reading these books*, and referencing the online MSDN documentation there still seem to be large gaps/flaws/errors in what is documented, and how the API works.

Is there any book about the SharePoint 2007 API that delves deeply into **everything**? I would think that Microsoft would commission/ship such a book? :)

---

*I've found "SharePoint 2007 Development Recipes - A Problem Solution Approach" by APress to be very helpful, but I think it barely scratches the surface of the API.

Comment: Did you need more resources or are you done with this question? Was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: I was hoping to get more info. The books so far, go into a few things, but not at the depth I was hoping.

Answer (score 4):

Look into the [Inside Microsoft Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=9692&locale=en-us)

I've had a lot of luck with this book, can't guarantee it goes into EVERYTHING, but it has mostly developer resources...

Comment: This was the most usefull book for me.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Mike above.  Also, [Inside Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623686) is a good reference.